# radio button grouping asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, overriding, viewstate

I am trying to group radiobuttons together with groupname property..
It doesnt work because of the naming convention in asp.net while rendering..

so i tried to inherited the radiobutton control and overrided radiobutton and created my own control..

it solved the grouping problem but its not taking care of viewstate for some reason...
so all my radiobuttons are are viewstate-less..

here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public class GroupRadioButton : RadioButton
    {
        public GroupRadioButton()
            : base()
        { }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(new GroupedRadioButtonTextWriter(writer,this.GroupName));
        }
    }

    public class GroupedRadioButtonTextWriter : HtmlTextWriter
    {
        private string groupName;

        public GroupedRadioButtonTextWriter(HtmlTextWriter baseWriter, string groupName) : base(baseWriter)
        {
            this.groupName = groupName;
        }

        public override void AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute key, string value)
        {
            if (key == HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name)
            {
                base.AddAttribute(key, this.groupName);
            }
            else
            {
                base.AddAttribute(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you explain in what way the GroupName property on the RadioButton does not work for you? Works like a charm for me (at least when I used to use WebForms). What version of ASP.NET WebForms are you using (I just retested with 4.0)

Comment: Have you tried a RadioButtonList? This will create a group of radiobuttons. All you need to do is bind a datasource to it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misused your time by implementing your own radio button considering the fact that [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) is the component you should be using.

Comment: radiobutton list will not fix the problem because button are at different place in the form.. :(

the radio button grouping is still not working for some reason..